# I am trying to use snowflake function to mask/hide set variable from query history

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and I am trying to Mask/Hide/de-identify Set variables on Snowflake query history.

```
SET VAR_PEPPER = '02-894083kjsadnlee'
```

when I check the query history I get this. the idea is to ensure the values of the variables are hidden/masked from the query history

[image]

Is there a function/way I can use to hide/de-identify the set variable from the query history

Comment: No, there isn't. If you can clarify why you would need to then there may be an alternative approach that will achieve what you want

Comment: @NickW thanks for the response, the pepper is meant to be a secret for creating a password hash function.

Comment: If you execute this using a role that no-one else has access to then no-one will be able to see it (apart from ACCOUNTADMINs). Alternatively, if you put this in a UDF then Query History should just show the call to the UDF but not the code within the UDF